# «Заморозка» пользовательского интерфейса

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver, android-ui

Цель: вызвать службу для регулярного прослушивания входящего потока BluetoothSocket.

Средства достижения цели:
1. В асинхронной задаче получить сокет и добавить его значение в вспомогательный класс:

```
        server = (BluetoothServerSocket) bluetooth.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("Game", UUID.fromString(Game.UUID));
        socket = server.accept();
        Game.getInstance().setBluetoothSocket(socket);
```

2. Если эта часть завершена без ошибки, то запустить службу (IntentService) (context - контекст активности, которая запускает эту задачу):

   ```
       context.startService(new Intent(context, InputStreamService.class));
   ```
3. Служба запущена и работает.

Но я сталкиваюсь с проблемой остановки приложения, будто служба выполняется в основном потоке. Но это невозможно, ведь служба - IntentService.

Я считаю недостатком постоянно работающие (зарегистрированные при запуске) широковещательные приёмники (ловят соединено устройство, рассоединено ли оно, состояние адаптера Bluetooth), в которых я только то и делаю, что взаимодействую с элементами интерфейса, но только один раз.

Вопрос: могут ли широковещательные приёмники причиной полной остановки приложения (без крушения)?

**Дополнительно:**

Проблема не в приёмниках.

Тут, на мой взгляд, всё прямо-таки безупречно:

```
public class InputStreamService extends IntentService {

Thread th;
Handler h = new Handler();
Intent error = new Intent(), newData, t;
InputStream input;
String inputData = "", oldData = "";
byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
Game game;


protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    game = Game.getInstance();
    error.setAction(Game.ERROR);
    th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (game.getBluetoothSocket() != null) {
                    input = game.getBluetoothSocket().getInputStream();
                    if (input.read() > 0) {
                        inputData = new String(buffer, 0, input.read(buffer));
                        if (!inputData.equals(oldData) && inputData.length() > 0) {
                            newData = new Intent();
                            newData.setAction(Game.NEW_DATA);
                            newData.putExtra("Data", inputData);
                            sendBroadcast(newData);
                            oldData = inputData;
                        };
                    };
                };
                h.postDelayed(th, 3000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sendBroadcast(error);
                h.removeCallbacks(th);
            };
        }
    });
    h.post(th);
};
```

Comment: По идее проверить можно так: закоментировать весь код в сервисе. Если после этого всё ОК - проблема в закомментрованном коде. Если дело не в этом - временно уберите все ресиверы и посмотрите исчезнет ли проблема. ИМХО дело таки в коде в сервисе.

Comment: Приёмник вызывается в основном потоке и может его тормознуть так же как и любой другой код. Насчёт службы - надеюсь вы знаете что только метод `onHandleIntent()` вызывается в фоновом потоке. Конструктор и методы жизненного цикла выполняются в главном.

Comment: `h.post(th);` - вот это для чего? Вы не запускаете поток, а отдаёте его хендлеру и если тот создан на главном потоке, то в нём и выполняет весь код.

Comment: @woesss, я проверял его работоспособность на Toast, он прекрасно работал. И в целом я считал этот способ единственным верным для использования кода с задержкой

Comment: @woesss, только не бейте. Не могли бы Вы подсказать, как правильнее реализовать его?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать `Handler` для выполнения фоновых задач, то нужно создать его c `Looper`, запущенном в фоновом потоке. Для удобства есть специальный тип потока [`HandlerThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread)

```
// подготовка (в методах ЖЦ или в том же onHandleIntent)
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("MyThread");
thread.start();
handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
```

Дальше, класс обычного потока не нужен, создаём задачу (`Runnable`) и её пинаем хендлеру:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    game = Game.getInstance();
    error.setAction(Game.ERROR);
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (game.getBluetoothSocket() != null) {
                    input = game.getBluetoothSocket().getInputStream();
                    if (input.read() > 0) {
                        inputData = new String(buffer, 0, input.read(buffer));
                        if (!inputData.equals(oldData) && inputData.length() > 0) {
                            newData = new Intent();
                            newData.setAction(Game.NEW_DATA);
                            newData.putExtra("Data", inputData);
                            sendBroadcast(newData);
                            oldData = inputData;
                        };
                    };
                };
                h.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sendBroadcast(error);
                h.removeCallbacks(this);
            };
        }
    };
    h.post(task);
};
```

По завершению работы с таким хендлером желательно вызвать

```
handler.getLooper().quit();
```

чтобы фоновый поток завершился.

Comment: Дорогой мой, не побоюсь этого слова, спаситель, я прочитал дополнительную литературу по Handler и инициализацию и присвоение значения я провёл в фоновом потоке. Надеюсь, это мне поможет (это помогло по первичным результатам). Огромное спасибо и за этот готовый код.